# C++/QT/ QTcreator Pass UI to a class and access controls

Tags: c++, qt

I made an application of a distributor which contains products in C++.
In this application I have a display class called "Afficheur" that display interaction with the user (selection of a product, insertion of coins,etc...).
To do this, I instantiated a "Facade" object and I call methods (insert,etc.) and because my Facade object contains a "Afficheur" object, each methods in Facade that I called, use the "Afficheur" to display message. 
But now, I made a QT UI(Mainwindow) with buttons,etc that represent the Facade (each click on controls in the ui call a Facade method) and I don't know who to pass the ui to my "Afficheur" class.
I've tried to change my Facade constructor to pass my Ui and pass it to the constructor of my Afficheur constructor to display message not on the console but on my Label in my Ui. But in the afficheur class I can't access to the controls so I gave up.

Here my mainwindow.cpp.

```
            #include "mainwindow.h"
            #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
            #include <QDebug>

            MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
                QMainWindow(parent),
                ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
            {

                ui->setupUi(this);
            }

            MainWindow::~MainWindow()
            {
                delete ui;
            }

            void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
            {
                facade->selection(0);
            }

            void MainWindow::on_btnThe_clicked()
            {
                facade->selection(1);
            }

            void MainWindow::on_btnChoco_clicked()
            {
                facade->selection(2);

            }

            void MainWindow::on_btn1Euro_clicked()
            {
                facade->insertion(1.0);
                facade->finDistribution();
                facade->monnaieRendue();
                //facade->
               // facade->controleur->
            }

            void MainWindow::on_btn50Cent_clicked()
            {
                facade->insertion(0.5);
            }

            void MainWindow::on_btn20Cent_clicked()
            {
                facade->insertion(0.2);
            }

            void MainWindow::on_btnCancel_clicked()
            {
                facade->annulation();
            }
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I found the solution, in my Afficheur class, I included `"ui_mainwindow.h"`and I changed the constructor to retrieve a `Ui::MainWindow* ui` object and now I can access to the several controls in the UI.
Of course, in my case, I also had to change my Facade class but this is a details.

Comment: Did you try using signals / slots to connect actions to displays ?

Comment: No I'm new with qt, so I don't know really how to do

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: thanks I'll look this

Comment: There's also the examples projects available from QtCreator to show it's done